# How to change radion button and checkbox in magento 1.9.2.1 - with images, and the use of :checked or :visited

Tags: attributes, magento-1, css

Im trying to change the radio buttons, so different `<label for="">` display an image. I would also like it to change the image with a new image, when the radio or check-box has been selected or checked.

The hover is working, and the boxes are marked as selected or checked. But I can't get the :checked working on me label.
From the form i'm using i'm not able to put in a class in the Labels, so it has to be the Label id (For="") as ref. for different  labels.

I'm using the standard `style.css` and a `custom.css` to override the buttons.

[image]

Here is my custom.css code

```
    label[for=options_2_3]{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}


span.label input:active +label[for=options_2_3]{opacity: .9;}
span.label input:checked +label[for=options_2_3]{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
label{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
label:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}

/* Extras */
a:visited{color:#888}
a{color:#444;text-decoration:none;}
p{margin-bottom:.3em;}
```

What Im trying to do exactly this from this Fiddle example:
Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BRoesink/875eqmn3/